# Where can I find the documentations for the data-react-helmet="true" attribute that is used with react-helmet/react-helmet-async?

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

I have seen the `data-react-helmet="true"` and the `data-rh="true"` tags used with `react-helmet-async`/`react-helmet` but, I can't find where they are used in the [documentation](https://github.com/staylor/react-helmet-async#readme). Where can I find documentation for these attribute so, that I can use them properly?